# Existing Java Pair Class with a twist

Tags: java

I am in a time crunch and haven't been able to find an answer that seems to work for this problem.

>
Assignment(Generic Class Pair) Write a generic class Pair which   has two type parameters--F and S -- each representing the type of the first and second element of the pair, respectively. Add get and set methods for the first and second elements of the pair.

Additional requirements:
- Default constructor
- Two argument constructor for data used to initialize "first" and "second"
- "toString" method for displaying the "first" and "second" data element
- Creates a "comparator"(ie. create an instance of a class that implements the interface and must override "compare" and "equals" methods)

-Application must create and ArrayList of 5 Pair objects then display the contents in sorted order largest to smallest based on compare method. 
-The class only supports types that extend Number. 
-Assume the "Pair" objects contain (x,y) coordinates, therefore calculate the distance from a (0,0) coordinate to determine the sorting order (ie. ascending, smallest to largest distance from (0,0)

So, below is what I have so far. 
I am hung up on the distance calculation, is it throwing an error since it is a default constructor (and will function as desired once "Number" type is entered?)
Also, I am not sure how to approach the creation of the ArrayList and display the sorted array based on the distance from (0,0). Thinking out loud from a logical standpoint the distance calculation is pointless since it is distance from (0,0).....this would just equal the same as the original (x,y) coordinate so it seems to just add some additional complicated steps just to get the sort ascending of the initial ArrayList.

```
public class Pair<F, S> {
//default constructor
private F first; //first member of pair
private S second; //second member of pair
public static final Pair origin = new Pair(0,0);

//two argument constructor
public Pair(F first, S second) {
    this.first = first;
    this.second = second;
}

public void setFirst(F first) {
    this.first = first;
}

public void setSecond(S second) {
    this.second = second;
}

public F getFirst() {
    return first;
}

public S getSecond() {
    return second;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return "("+ this.first + ", "+ this.second + ")";
}
 public float distanceTo(Pair other) {
    float Fchg = other.getFirst() - this.getFirst();
    float Schg = other.getSecond() - this.getSecond();
    return Math.sqrt(Fchg * Fchg + Schg * Schg);
}

}
```

---

Updated Code

```
public abstract class Pair <F, S> extends Number {
//default constructor
private F first; //first member of pair
private S second; //second member of pair  

//two argument constructor
public Pair(F first, S second) {
    this.first = first;
    this.second = second;
}

public void setFirst(F first) {
    this.first = first;
}

public void setSecond(S second) {
    this.second = second;
}

public F getFirst() {
    return first;
}

public S getSecond() {
    return second;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return "("+ this.first + ", "+ this.second + ")";
}

public double distanceTo(Pair other) {
    double firstChange = other.getFirst() - this.getFirst();
    double secondChange = other.getSecond() - this.getSecond();
    return Math.sqrt(firstChange * firstChange + secondChange * secondChange);
}
}
```

Comment: Hint: Why would `other.getFirst() - this.getFirst();` be a `float`? You've defined `first` to be of type `F`. How do you subtract elements of type `F`? And what type is the result?

Comment: @Elliott Frisch my line of thought was that the (x,y) coordinates would be float (just an assumption). I wasn't sure how to approach calculations from a default constructor. Looking back at my code using that logic I should have made origin (0.0,0.0) I guess.

Comment: `The class only supports types that extend Number`. This is an important piece of the assignment. Think about it with your `Pair` class, how are you enforcing this requirement? (Hint: you're not)

Comment: @nickb Thank you for pointing that out to me, so I extended Number but it is still throwing the same errors....and no longer likes the <public static final Pair origin = new Pair(0,0);> piece......

Comment: Show your updated code. I'd indent and format it better too. Also, `Fchg` and `Schg` aren't good variable names and violate Java naming standards. Only class / interface names start with an upper case letter. Try `firstChange` and `secondChange`, if that's the naming you prefer.

Comment: @nickb I added my updated code

Comment: Looking at your requirements, you should have a generic `Pair<F,S>` interface that is implemented by a `Coordinates` class where F and S are `Number` (or subclasses of `Number`) that defines the `distanceTo(Coordinates other)` method and uses it in its `compare` and `equalsTo` methods.

Comment: @Aaron thank you for the input, can you give me an idea of how that would look......ie. how I would implement Pair from Coordinates? Would it extend Pair or a completely different approach altogether?

Comment: You're close, but `Pair <F, S> extends Number` is not what you're looking for. It should be `Pair <F extends Number, S extends Number>`. This enforces that somebody can use numbers for the generic values.

Comment: @brroes I meant `Coordinates implements Pair<Integer, Integer>`

Comment: @nickb thank you, you've been a big help

Comment: @Aaron thank you, that clears it up for me, thanks again for the help